# counting, circular permutation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are $n$ students around the table. They all have an empty paper.

Let a set $S$ be $S=\left\lbrace 1,\omega,\omega^2 \right\rbrace$.

Each students take only one element in $S$.

But the product of two arbitrary consecutive students is not $1$.

Count all possible cases.

I tried to use relation between $n$-th term and $(n+1)$-th term, but failed.

I counted directly $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. Then the number of cases are

$3, 6, 8, 18, 32$.

But, I want to solve the problem generally.

Please help me. Thank you.

($\omega$ is a root of $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$)

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If the students were sitting in a line (instead of around a circle), then the answer would be $3\times2^{n-1}$ – can you see that? It's plausible that one-third of the time the first and last students will multiply to 1, so if we're going to bend that line into a circle, we have to reject one-third of the $3\times2^{n-1}$, leaving us with $2^n$, which agrees with your calculations for $n\ge3$. Not quite a proof, I know, but maybe fixable.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have serious error;; for n = 4, not 16. The number of case for n = 4 is 18. I'm very sorry......

Comment: What is the product of two students?  What is $\omega?$

Comment: For a given $n$ let there be $k\ 1$'s around the table.  We cannot have any of the ones next to each other.  In the gap between a pair of $1$'s all the numbers must be the same, but each gap can be $\omega$ or $\omega^2$ independently.  Therefore for each arrangement of $k\ 1$'s there are $2^k$ total arrangements, except that if $k=0$ there are still $2$ arrangements and if $n=k=1$ there is only one arrangement because there are no $\omega$'s or $\omega^2$'s.  I have not been able to find the number of ways to distribute $k\ 1$'s among $n$ places with no $1$'s next to each other.

Comment: Any thoughts, mero, on the answer I posted two days ago?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $2^n+1+(-1)^n$. Given the simplicity of this answer, there's probably a simple way to get to it, but I had to take a lengthy route.

Consider students in a line (not a circle – we'll get to that), starting with a 1. Let $r_n$ be the number of lists of length $n$ ending in 1, $s_n$ the number ending in $\omega$, $t_n$ the number ending in $\omega^2$. We get the system $r_n=s_{n-1}+t_{n-1}$, $s_n=r_{n-1}+s_{n-1}$, $t_n=r_{n-1}+t_{n-1}$. So $$\pmatrix{r_n\cr s_n\cr t_n\cr}=\pmatrix{0&1&1\cr1&1&0\cr1&0&1\cr}\pmatrix{r_{n-1}\cr s_{n-1}\cr t_{n-1}\cr}$$ That matrix has eigenvalues $2,1,-1$, so $r_n=A(2)^n+B+C(-1)^n$ for some real constants $A,B,C$. The initial values are $r_2=0$, $r_3=2$, $r_4=2$ (e.g., the two sequences of length 4 beginning and ending with 1 are $1\omega\omega1$ and $1\omega^2\omega^21$), so we get $A=1/6$, $B=0$, $C=-2/3$. We get similar formulas for $s_n$ and $t_n$, as they satisfy the same recurrence, but with different initial values ($s_2=1$, $s_3=1$, $s_4=3$, likewise for $t_n$).

Then you do the same thing for sequences starting with $\omega$, and then for sequences starting with $\omega^2$. Then, you add them all up, leaving out the sequences starting and ending with 1, the sequences starting with $\omega$ and ending with $\omega^2$, and the sequences starting with $\omega^2$ and ending with $\omega$ (thus leaving out the lines that can't be closed up to a circle), and what comes out is the formula at the top of this answer.